# How to stop a form from resubmitting

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to add additional functionality to a web site including the ability for a form to only be submitted once, this is so that when the user refreshes everything is not processed again etc.

I have looked at a few pieces of code using Jquery and javascript but was wondering if there was any way to do this in Coldfusion, and how do other people who use Coldfusion do it? I am looking for the most simple yet effective solution if possible.

Below is an example of a form that I would like to disable "resubmit" funtionality:

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm">
<cfparam name="form.step" default="1">
<cfparam name="form.submit" default="">
<cfparam name="form.finish" default="">

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = 1;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
currentItem++;
$('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Itemname'+currentItem+'" id="Itemname'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" id="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="Quantity'+currentItem+'" id="Quantity'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input type="text" name="Code'+currentItem+'" id="Code'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input type="text" name="Price'+currentItem+'" id="Price'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td></tr>';
  $('#data').append(strToAdd);

 });
 });

 //]]>
 </script>

<cfif form.finish eq "finish">
    <cflocation addtoken="no" url="inv_new.cfm">
</cfif>
<form id="formID" method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="CopyWhite" align="left" background="images/tab_bg.gif" colspan="2">Add a new invoice</td>
</tr>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif form.step eq 1>
            <cfquery name="get_vendors" datasource="#application.db#">
                SELECT * FROM tblpassVendor
                WHERE vendorActive = 1
                AND CompanyID = #session.companyid#
                AND VendorID IN (#GetAdmin.AdminVendors#)
            </cfquery>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Invoice Using:</td>
                <td>
                    <Select name="INVBY">
                        <cfloop query="get_vendors">
                            <option value="#vendorid#">#vendorname#</option>
                        </cfloop>
                    </Select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
                <input type="Reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" class="submitbutton">
                </td>
            </tr>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 2>
            <input type="hidden" name="vendor" value="#FORM.INVBY#" />
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Order Details:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Payment Due:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="date1" class="validate[required]" name="INVPAYMENTDATE" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Reference Number:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="REFNUM" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Invoice Details:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Pay Using Masterpass:</td>
                <td style="color:##000">
                    <input type="radio" name="MASTERPASS" value="1" checked="yes"> Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="MASTERPASS" value="0" checked="no"> No<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Pay Using Iveri:</td>
                <td style="color:##000">
                    <input type="radio" name="IVERI" value="1" checked="yes"> Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="IVERI" value="0" checked="no"> No<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Pay Using Other:</td>
                <td style="color:##000">
                    <input type="radio" name="OTHER" value="1" checked="yes"> Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="OTHER" value="0" checked="no"> No<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Billing Details:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="NAME" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Surname:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="LNAME" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Tel:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="TEL" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="EMAIL" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Address line 1:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="ADDR1" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Address line 2:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="ADDR2" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">City/Town:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="CITY" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Province/Region:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="REGION" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Country:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="COUNTRY" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">ZIP/Postal Code:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="ZIP" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3" />
                <input type="Reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" class="submitbutton">
                </td>
            </tr>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 3>
        <cftry>
            <cfset payuid = "#CreateUUID()#">
            <cfset invuid = "#CreateUUID()#">
            <!---WRITE DATA TO TBLINV--->
            <cfquery name="write_inv" datasource="#application.db#" result="test">
                INSERT INTO tblpassInv
                (INVVENDORID,INVREF,INVNAME,INVLNAME,INVTEL,INVEMAIL,INVADDR1,INVADDR2,INVCITY,INVREGION,INVCOUNTRY,INVZIP,INVCOMPANY,INVCREATEDBY,INVDATECREATED,INVACTIVE,INVSEND,paymentuid,invuid,invmasterpass,inviveri,invother,invpaymentdate)
                VALUES
                (#form.vendor#,'#form.REFNUM#','#form.NAME#','#form.LNAME#','#form.TEL#','#form.EMAIL#','#form.ADDR1#','#form.ADDR2#','#form.CITY#','#form.REGION#','#form.COUNTRY#','#form.ZIP#',#session.companyid#,#session.adminid#,#createodbcdatetime(now())#,1,0,'#payuid#','#invuid#',#form.MASTERPASS#,#form.IVERI#,#form.OTHER#,'#FORM.INVPAYMENTDATE#')
            </cfquery>
            <cfset NewPrimaryKey = test.GENERATED_KEY>
            <!---<cfinclude template="inv_amend_prods_new.cfm">--->
            <tr>
            <td>
            <table  id="data">
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Products/Line Items:</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="Itemname1" id="Itemname1" class="TextBlock">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="ItemDesc1" id="ItemDesc1" class="TextBlock">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" name="Quantity1" id="Quantity1" class="TextBlock">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="Code1" id="Code1" class="TextBlock"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Price: (eg. 100.00)</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" name="Price1" id="Price1" class="TextBlock"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                    <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#NewPrimaryKey#" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <cfcatch type="any">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("An error has occured! Please try again later")
                </script>
            </cfcatch>
            </cftry>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 4> 
        <cftry>       
            <cfloop from="1" to="#FORM.items#" index="i">
                <cfset thisname = form["Itemname" & i]>
                <cfset thisdesc = form["ItemDesc" & i]>
                <cfset thisqty = form["Quantity" & i]>
                <cfset thiscode = form["Code" & i]>
                <cfset thisprice = form["Price" & i]>
                <cfset thisprice = replace("#thisprice#",".","","All")>
                <cfquery name="add_items" datasource="#application.db#">
                    INSERT INTO tblpassInvItems
                    (invid,itemactive,itemname,itemdesc,itemqty,itemcode,itemprice)
                    VALUES
                        (#form.invid#,1,'#thisname#','#thisdesc#',#thisqty#,'#thiscode#','#thisprice#')
                </cfquery>
            </cfloop>

            <cfset invid = form.invid>
            <cfinclude template="inv_doc.cfm">
                <tr>
                    <td class="Copy" valign="top">Display all details for invoice:</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="copy" valign="top">Download</td>
                    <td><a href="dynamicdocs/#this_filename#.pdf" target="_blank" title="Download">Download</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                    <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="5" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#form.invid#" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <!---<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=#this_filename#.pdf">
            <cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" file="#expandPath('.')#/dynamicdocs/#this_filename#.pdf" deletefile="No">--->
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("An error has occured! Please try again later")
            </script>
        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 5>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top" colspan="2">Please complete the following if you would like to send the invoice now or click on finish:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Bcc:</td>
                <td>
                    <cfquery name="get_vendors" datasource="#application.db#">
                        SELECT * FROM tblpassVendor
                        WHERE vendorActive = 1
                        AND CompanyID = #session.companyid#
                        AND VendorID IN (#GetAdmin.AdminVendors#)
                    </cfquery>
                    <Select name="bcc">
                        <cfloop query="get_vendors">
                            <option value="#vendorbccemail#">#vendorbccemail#</option>
                        </cfloop>
                    </Select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="6" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#form.invid#" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="inv_new.cfm" title="Finish">Save and Start New Invoice</a></td>
            </tr>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 6>
        <cftry>
        <cfset invid = form.invid>
        <cfinclude template="inv_mail.cfm">
        <tr>
            <td class="Copy" valign="top" colspan="2">Thank you! Your Invoice has been sent!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="copy" valign="top"></td>
            <td><a href="inv_new.cfm" title="Finish">Finish</a></td>
        </tr>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top" colspan="2">An Error has occured! Your invoice has not been sent</td>
            </tr>
        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
</table>
</form>
<cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

I am not using things like cfqueryparam as this is still being developed and is within a secure environment

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @Raptor I did not post any code because I would just like to have a general Idea, using <form> or <cfform> and posting the form only once no matter what it contains, but i will update my question with an example of what I am using

Comment: Have you googled "multistep form" and looked at the various results?

Comment: Thanks @Adam found something that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do something like this (used it long time back, code may be off, but more of an idea):

```
<cfparam name="form.submitted" default=0>
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM,"submit") AND NOT FORM.submitted>
<!---action code goes here--->
<cfset form.submitted=1>
</cfif>
<form>
<!--- your other form elements--->
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="#FORM.submitted#">
</form>
```

I am not sure, it can help you much in multi-step form, but it helped in single step avoiding multi-submit by setting the flag when the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the same page, it will avoid re-posting the form.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, what if all of my forms are on the same page? I use hidden values to display a different section of the form after each submit action.

Comment: Sure this is not the best solution, it is what I did when I faced same problem. Agree with @Deepak's answer below, another option can be AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of situation few days back. As per my knowledge the best possible solutions are,

1. Redirect to some other page for preventing form resubmission.
2. If redirect is not suitable , the only other option is using AJAX.